# What is a createLegacyRoot in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

I'm trying to replicate the same example as the react doc for [context section](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html), combined with react hook, but react devtool informs that my context is rendered by `createLegacyRoot()` from `react-dom@17.0.2`. It doesn't have any functionality issue, but I just wonder why it is legacy, is there any new way for creating context which is going to be proposed.

[image]

Here is what I'm doing.

```
const ThemeContext = React.createContext()

function ContextApp() {
  const [theme, setTheme] = React.useState('light')

  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={[theme, setTheme]}>
      <ThemeSwitcherUseContext />
      <ThemeInformationClass />
      <ThemeInformationOldStyleConsumer />
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  )
}


const ThemeSwitcherUseContext = () => {
  const [theme, setTheme] = React.useContext(ThemeContext)
  return (
    <button onClick={() => setTheme(theme === 'light' ? 'dark' : 'light')}>
      Switch to {theme === 'light' ? 'dark' : 'light'}
    </button>
  )
}

class ThemeInformationClass extends React.Component {
  static contextType = ThemeContext
  render() {
    return <div>class Theme="{this.context[0]}"</div>
  }
}

const ThemeInformationOldStyleConsumer = () => (
  <ThemeContext.Consumer>
    {([theme]) => <div>function Theme="{theme}"</div>}
  </ThemeContext.Consumer>
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This refers to concurrent mode that will be launching with React 18, the new syntax is

```
ReactDOM.createRoot(rootNode).render(<App />);
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-reference.html